# How to join laravel queries to called data from different table?

Tags: laravel, api, ionic3

I just being able to call the API separately. I want to call user clinic data from table users and other clinic data in table clinic  How can I join the queries and display it as one list.The table users and clinic are related by uid. Id number for users is equal to uid clinic.

What I have tried is I called queries separately.

**.api**

```
$clinicData = User::where('uid',$id)->first();

$clinicProfile = RegisterClinic::where('uid',$clinicData->id)->first();
```

I want it to call in one query only because I want to call back in one API.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have the below relation ship,

`User Model`

```
public function RegisterClinic(){
   $this->hasOne(RegisterClinic::class, 'uid', 'id');
}
```

then try below one,

```
$clinicData = User::with('RegisterClinic')->where('uid',$id)->first();
```

this will give you the result like

```
[{
  'uid':123,
   ........,
   RegisterClinic : {
      'uid':123,
      ...........
   }
}]
```

Comment: The users(User) table is related to the clinic(RegisterClinic) table. So should it have a model?

Comment: The table users and clinic are related by uid. Id number for users is equal to uid clinic. I updated the question there.

Comment: Both table should have different model.  then only the relations will work.